# Google Cloud ML Engine Admin Role Disappeared

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, google-ai-platform

[This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras#authenticate_your_gcp_account) from Google states that I need to give a service account the roles

- "Machine Learning Engine > ML Engine Admin"
- "Storage > Storage Object Admin"

in order to send jobs to be trained and saved in the cloud. I don't see these roles being offered in the Google Console IAM Service Account role list anymore. Have they been moved or renamed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently "ML Engine Admin" role does not exists anymore. Based from the tutorial you are referring to, you need permissions to do training and prediction in AI Platform.

You can use "AI Platform Admin" which will grant you full access to AI Platform [training](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/access-control#project_roles) and [prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/access-control#project_roles) resources. See [AI Platform roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#ai-platform-roles) for other available roles.

> [image]

Searchable role in "IAM & Admin":
[image]